# Why the fragment only shows on create and after tab switch?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

So, in the current state, I can see the fragment inside, showing when I boot up the virtual phone; however, as soon as I switch to different fragment, from my drawer, and switch back again into the fragment, with the `tableLayout`, its shows nothing! Plus, switching between the tabs does seem to fix it.

[You can see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2XWx.png)

Here is the code:

```java
package com.example.teamapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;

public class HomeFragmentNav extends Fragment {

    FragmentManager fragmentManagerHome;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tableLayout;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    TabItem TeamsTab;
    TabItem ChatTab;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_nav, container, false);

        tableLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.TabBar);
        TeamsTab = v.findViewById(R.id.TeamsTab);
        ChatTab = v.findViewById(R.id.ChatTab);
        viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        tableLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
        tableLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
        fragmentManagerHome = getFragmentManager();
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManagerHome,
            tableLayout.getTabCount(), getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        tableLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        tableLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.TabBar);
        TeamsTab = v.findViewById(R.id.TeamsTab);
        ChatTab = v.findViewById(R.id.ChatTab);
        viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
        tableLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
        tableLayout.getTabAt(0).select();
        fragmentManagerHome = getFragmentManager();
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManagerHome,
            tableLayout.getTabCount(), getContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the page from refreshing.

view_pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);

Comment: adding it didn't change anything, I assume this line should help by preventing heavy loading time, the thing is nothing is loading even if i will leave it for an hour, for now I cant imagine why only on first create it works well

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I used `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getChildFragmentManager()`